# VBA: Trying to build a dynamic array from column text

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm a VBA newbie and I'm trying to make an array from some text (i.e. the names of the worksheets) I have listed out in a column ("B") - so I can save all my worksheets as a single PDF file, but with the option of adding or removing worksheets over time (as in, rewriting them under wksAllSheets over and over again).

So far I have:

```
Public Sub saveAsPDF()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Call print_reports 'a sub I created with the printing layours
    Dim wksAllSheets As Variant
    Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim strFilename, strName As String, strFilepath As String

    Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetCOVER") 'reference ws
    wksAllSheets = Array("SheetCOVER", "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", _
                        "Sheet5", _
                        "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8")



    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wksAllSheets).Select
    wksSheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strFilename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    wksSheet1.Select

    Sheets("Home").Select


End Sub
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!!

Comment: It's not clear here what the specific issue/problem is. Does the code behave unexpectedly? does it give an error?

Comment: Do you mean you want to populate `wksAllSheets` array dynamicaly with the sheets written down in Column B ? you can use something like `wksAllSheets = Application.Transpose(Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to dynamically build  the list of sheets you can use the sheets collection

```
For Each ws In Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Home","COVER" ' exclude these sheets
        Case Else 'include all others
            wksAllSheets = wksAllSheets & IIf(wksAllSheets = "", "", ",") & ws.Name
        End Select
    Next
    wksAllSheets = Split(wksAllSheets, ",")
```

to build the list from a specific column in a sheet of your workbook

```
wksallsheets=application.transpose(sheets("listpdf").range("B1:B" & sheets("listpdf").cells(rows.count,"B").end(xlup).row))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. Forgive me for the silly question, but how should I change  wksSheet1 to in (?) : wksSheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strFilename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    wksSheet1.Select

Comment: the proposed instructions is to replace this instruction `wksAllSheets = Array("COVER", "CUR", "RANK_NS", "RANK_PC", "RANK_BAGS", _
                        "RANK_BAGS_MAN", _
                        "RANK_BELTS", "RANK_FJ_WOM", "RANK_FURS_WOM", _
                        "RANK_KIDS", "RANK_RTW_MAN", "RANK_SHOES_WOM", _
                        "RANK_RTW_WOM", "RANK_WATCHES", "RANK_SLG_MAN", _
                        "RANK_SLG_WOM") 'CHANGE HERE` I didn't look at the remaining of the code, as my understanding is that it is working fine

Comment: Sorry I must have altered something else because the code didn't run yesterday. I did it again today, but I just realized my mistake: I don't want to print out ALL the worksheets in the workbook, but only those listed in a column in a specific sheet. Would there be a way to do this?

Comment: @sealingkarma see comment of Shai Rado earlier. just replace my proposed instructions by his.

Comment: Unfortunately Shai Rado's proposal doesn't work because it reads the columns values and isn't able to refer to the worksheets... (ie. I get a runtime error 9 saying its out of range.

Comment: add the name of the worksheet before the range/cells instruction like : `sheets("listpdf").range("B1:B" & sheets("listpdf").cells(rows.count,"B").end(xlup).row)`

Comment: I did  that, but unfortunately it seems to read the values on the column, but I get a runtime error 13 (mismatched type) when the code runs down to [ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wksAllSheets).Select]

Comment: **Do not** use string math (as in `Range("B1:B" & n)`), but rather the proper  way of `Range("B1").Resize(n,1)`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I managed to fix it using @h2so4 and Shai Rado's help and a little modification. what do you mean proper way?

Comment: @h2so4 - Error-prone, difficult to maintain, absolute addressing, slow, does not handle well (structural) changes in the workbook, difficult to debug and does not follow best practices for VBA. Too bad SO/Documentation went away because there was an awesome post on this there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create an array from a table starting from "B1"

```
Dim n_rows as Long, n_cols as Long
Dim r as Range

Set r = Range("B1")
' Count non-empty cells
n_rows = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
n_cols = 1  ' Assume table has one column.
' Set the range variable 'r' to the entire table of cells
Set r = r.Resize(n_rows, n_cols)

Dim vals() as Variant  ' This is the dynamic array spec
vals = r.Value         ' Here you fill the array from the cells

Dim i as Long
For i=1  to n_rows
    Debug.Pring vals(i,1)    'You access the array with (i,j): i=row, j=column
Next i
```